# Gradle ant build file not not available during configuration phase

Tags: groovy, gradle, ant, build.gradle

I can't figure out how to execute ant target in case that ant **build.xml file is not available during configuration phase**. Because it's a remote resource (Maven Remote Resources Plugin).

So basically first I need to get this remote resource like this:

```
configurations {
    remoteResources
}

dependencies.remoteResources 'group:my-remote-resource:version'

task getRemoteResources(type: Copy) {
    from(zipTree(configurations.remoteResources.first()))
    into("$buildDir/remote-resources")

    // replace placeholders
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, , tokens: remotePlaceholders)
}
```

Only then I have build.xml in

```
"$buildDir/remote-resources"
```

But I can't use **ant.importBuild** as that expects build.xml to be available during the configuration, which is not my case.

I was thinking to move the remote resource "download" into initialization phase, but I have a multi-module project and although only some sub-projects are using this remote resource they all has it own placeholders to replace.

Is there any way how to execute ant targets in this special case?

EDIT: I found pretty nice [solution](http://groovy-almanac.org/using-ant-buildxml-and-antbuilder/) utilising Ant's ProjectHelper and Project classes. So I guess that is my answer..

Comment: You can answer your own question. That may will help some else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the final solution. (as already mentioned credits go to [groovy-almanac](http://groovy-almanac.org/using-ant-buildxml-and-antbuilder/))

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper;

task executeAntTarget(dependsOn: getRemoteResources) << {
    def antFile = new File("$buildDir/remote-resources/build.xml")
    def antProject = new Project()
    antProject.init()
    ProjectHelper.projectHelper.parse(antProject, antFile)

    antProject.executeTarget('<target-to-execute>');
}
```